# Postgres broken inheritance?

Tags: postgresql

After using `DROP COLUMN column_name` on parent table some columns in the child tables are not deleted.

How to reassign columns with this behaviour for correct cascade deleting in future?

How to reproduce:
There are two tables: `parent` and `child`. Child is inherited from the parent and has same columns.
Add new column `test` in child. Add new column `test` in parent. After that `test` in child becomes inherited from parent.
Try to drop `test` from parent - expecting cascade deleting `test` from child. But it stays.

```
CREATE TABLE parent (a INT);
CREATE TABLE child () INHERITS (parent);
ALTER TABLE child ADD COLUMN test_inherit VARCHAR;
ALTER TABLE parent ADD COLUMN test_inherit VARCHAR;
ALTER TABLE parent DROP COLUMN test_inherit;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on `After that test in child becomes inherited from parent.` - is there documentation stating that it becomes inherited? I can't find any, just that they are "merged". Based solely on observation, it appears that a column explicitly created on a child table will *not* be considered inherited even if the parent table subsequently gets a column of that same name.

Comment: Good question. The code from this answer shows parent columns for the particular column https://stackoverflow.com/a/9178440/9521312. And when you'll try to change ```test``` column in child you'll get error about inherited column. So I made a conclusion that child column becomes inherited from parent, maybe it's wrong.

Comment: This is a very interesting question. The linked query is based on `pg_inherits` which just has table ids. It gets all columns from that. But there must be more to it. If you create a `parent` table, and a `child` table which inherits `parent`, add columns *only* to `parent`, then drop from `parent`, they are dropped in the child. But if you first do this: `ALTER TABLE child NO INHERIT parent` then `ALTER TABLE child INHERIT parent`, so remove and re-add inheritance, then drop columns in `parent`, none of them are dropped in `child`. So it appears inheritance doesn't work for "merged" columns.

Comment: Yes, I hoped to fix these "broken" fields in legacy DB by `NO INHERIT` and `INHERIT` sequence. But with no luck =\

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What happens here is that the columns on table `child` are not marked as inherited columns:

```
CREATE TABLE parent (a INT);
CREATE TABLE child (a INT) INHERITS (parent);
NOTICE:  merging column "a" with inherited definition
ALTER TABLE child ADD COLUMN test_inherit VARCHAR;
ALTER TABLE parent ADD COLUMN test_inherit VARCHAR;
NOTICE:  merging definition of column "test_inherit" for child "child"

SELECT attname, attnum, attislocal
FROM pg_attribute
WHERE attrelid = 'child'::regclass AND attnum > 0;

   attname    | attnum | attislocal 
--------------+--------+------------
 a            |      1 | t
 test_inherit |      2 | t
(2 rows)
```

`attislocal` means that it is a column that was defined on `child` directly, not automatically created because of inheritance from another table.

If you define the child table without any columns, the columns will be inherited columns:

```
DROP TABLE parent, child;
CREATE TABLE parent (a INT, test_inherit VARCHAR);
CREATE TABLE child () INHERITS (parent);

SELECT attname, attnum, attislocal
FROM pg_attribute
WHERE attrelid = 'child'::regclass AND attnum > 0;

   attname    | attnum | attislocal 
--------------+--------+------------
 a            |      1 | f
 test_inherit |      2 | f
(2 rows)
```

Only inherited columns are dropped if the column in the inheritance parent are dropped:

```
ALTER TABLE parent DROP COLUMN test_inherit;

\d child
               Table "laurenz.child"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 a      | integer |           |          | 
Inherits: parent
```

Comment: Great! Searching this attr through DB will show all "broken" fields. Thank you! But edit please your second example and create `test_inherit` fields in order: child first, parent next. Problem is still here. But flag `attislocal` solves my problem "how to find and fix these fields". Thanks again.

Comment: PS edited code in question for more clear instructions.

Comment: My second example shows how to create the tables in the "regular" fashion so that the columns are inherited. Of course, if you create `child` first, the columns won't be inherited.

Comment: And interesting fact about inherit property of column. If you'll try to edit `test_inherit` column in child which was created before parent, you'll get an error from Postgre `sql> ALTER TABLE child ALTER COLUMN test_inherit TYPE INT
[2019-06-19 16:32:21] [42P16] ERROR: cannot alter inherited column "test_inherit"`. So is it legit to call this column as not inherited? Quote from docs about `attislocal`: `Note that a column can be locally defined and inherited simultaneously`. There is no information in docs that cascade dropping inheritance fields doesn't affects locally created attrib.

Comment: Good point. I have edited the answer and improved the description of `attislocal`.